# I keep getting an error that my app needs to be verified when either I or another user try to authorize with OAuth2. What does that mean?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I received this error when trying to authorize my app with my own account:

```
Your project is trying to access scopes that need to go through the verification process.

{invalid=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts}

If you need to use one of these scopes, submit a verification request. Learn More
```

When I use a different account, the error message is different:

```
This app hasn’t been verified to access:
{invalid=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts}


Are you the developer? If this project needs these scopes, sign in to an account with access to edit your project and try again.

If not, contact the developer for help.
```

Answer (score 22):

As per the [announcement](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html) on May 11, 2017, publicly available applications with access to certain user data must pass review. If you see an access error for your app, submit a request using our [OAuth Developer Verification](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) form.

For personal-use apps and those you are testing, join the Google group [Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps), which allows you to approve data access for personal and testing accounts. See the [Google API Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy) for more information.

UPDATE: Corrected broken link to form.

Comment: Here is the _correct_ URL for [OAuth Developer Verification](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification).

Comment: I've joined that Google Group - how long usually until access is granted for me to be able to use my own accounts for testing? If anyone from Google is reading this for the love of God please consider writing better, spoonfed documentation because this guessing game is ridiculous.

Comment: @Simpleton After I joined the Google Group, I was immediately able to use my own account for testing. I also made a [tutorial](https://www.cloudsponge.com/blog/google-oauth-reviews/) on applying for an OAuth review. I hope it's useful to anyone facing this issue even though I wrote it specifically for CloudSponge customers.

Comment: wow, how would anyone know to do this? As far as I saw, it's not directly in the Google API's OAuth2 documentation or linked to and the error message is completely useless in debugging the issue. This answer saved me a lot of time / frustration though, thanks!

Comment: It's amazing how the masters of the search engine manage to obfuscate everything. Finding your way around in their systems is a nightmare.

Comment: The group linked is now marked as blocked. Is there any updated information about how to join the group?

Comment: Same here - unable to join this group

Comment: Me too. Cannot join this group. Damn.