# Invalid scope error when trying to access gmail api

Tags: javascript, python, apache, gmail, gmail-api

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_scope

You don't have permission to access some scopes. Your project is trying to access scopes that need to go through the verification process. {invalid = [https:// mail.google.com/]} If you need to use one of these scopes, submit a verification request.
```

This is the error that I am getting when I flowed the tutorial in this link:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

In the link they asked me to access webserver via python but I am using apache.
So in the step 1.f,  Authorized JavaScript origins: am using the link http:// localhost instead of http:// localhost:8000. What might be causing the error??

Comment: have you submitted a verification request for `[https://mail.google.com/]` scope, like the error suggests you need to?

Comment: verification request is leading to link: https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification?id=783306915704&client=783306915704-s8c3vajfdlvjj21bu6qaqhos9c352j8g.apps.googleusercontent.com&query=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly . But same when i tried with php it worked well.. Didnt asked for any verification.. But I want to implement in JS..

Comment: Not sure if you got that, but it's a matter of google's API scope, as in the information you request from them. That means you do not have access to certain informations without asking for specific permissions, and has -allegedly- nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928334/i-keep-getting-an-error-that-my-app-needs-to-be-verified-when-either-i-or-anothe).

> As per the [announcement](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html) on May 11, 2017, publicly available applications with access to certain user data must pass review. If you see an access error for your app, submit a request using our [OAuth Developer Verification](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) form.
>
> For personal-use apps and those you are testing, join the Google group [Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps), which allows you to approve data access for personal and testing accounts. See the [Google API Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy) for more information.

This [blog](https://blog.zubairalexander.com/how-to-fix-the-invalid_scope-error-in-wordpress-postman-smtp-plugin/) about how to fix this error might be also helpful.