# Gmail JS API - OAuth2 Error invalid_scope

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am new to GMail JS API and I was trying to read gmail emails using Javascript according to the quickstart tutorial given explained on below link

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

I have followed all the instructions given on the page but I am getting below 
error

[image]

did I miss something???

Please help me resolve this error

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667951/5832311). Make sure that you are authenticated to the API properly.

> To do this, there are two ways:
>
> - use OAuth - the Server redirects the user to google's servers, where they can login, grant permission to your app, and pass a token back to
>     you
> - Service Accounts. These are a little bit more complicated:
>
>   - First, you'll have to setup an app (done)
>   - second, you'll have to setup a service account. This is how your app authenticates to google. you've done that, and the certificate
>       you've got contains the private key to authenticate
>   - third, the user needs to grant your application access to act on behalf of them. This is the point you haven't done yet.

Also, as stated [here](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/88), certain scopes simply aren't supported for the oauth2 for devices flow.

Additional references:

- [Invalid scope error when trying to access gmail api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363021/invalid-scope-error-when-trying-to-access-gmail-api)

  > You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928334/i-keep-getting-an-error-that-my-app-needs-to-be-verified-when-either-i-or-anothe).
  >
  > As per the [announcement](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html) on May 11, 2017, publicly available applications with access to certain user data must pass review. If you see an access error for your app, submit a request using our [OAuth Developer Verification](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) form.
  >
  > For personal-use apps and those you are testing, join the Google group [Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps), which allows you to approve data access for personal and testing accounts. See the [Google API Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy) for more information.
  >
  > This [blog](https://blog.zubairalexander.com/how-to-fix-the-invalid_scope-error-in-wordpress-postman-smtp-plugin/) about how to fix this error might be also helpful.
- [OAuth invalid scope](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/hangouts/LU2YZNDhN_s/nF9n8MEXDgAJ)

Comment: Followed all the steps listed above i.e. create service account and clicked on allow in the popup window using my Gmail Account but still the same error...